# MongoDB Indexes, is it possible to create both normal & compound at the same time?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, compound-index, nosql

I have to create indexes for a MongoDb collection:

**Users**

- _id
- app_version
- countryCode
- facebook_id
- token
- userid
- device_id

1.The 30% of the queries are
    **{_id, token,device_id}**

2.Other common queries (30%) are
    **{_id, token}**

3.And the rest (40%) are queries using individually: 
    **{_id}**
    **{device_id}**
    **{userid}**
    **{facebook_id}**

I don´t know how to manage that.
I am almost sure that i need to create a compound index on **{_id:"1" , token:"1",device_id:"1"}** .
My questions are:

a)Would the compound index optimize the first and the second case,right?

b)What should i do with the case 3?Create indexes for each field?

Thanks!

Comment: Do queries include all of the fields? For example, a query involving all of {_id, token,device_id}?

Comment: No ,i have differenciated queries:{_id, token,device_id}, {_id,token} {_id},{userid},{device_id},{facebook_id}.These are all the queries @ naimdjon

Comment: Yes, due to the tree like mechanisms of compound indexes in MongoDB you would do scenario three as 4 separate indexes. Though _id is already indexed

Comment: @Sammaye and what is answer for question a?

Comment: The answer would be yes there, providing that you only query by `{_id, token, device_id}` or `{_id, token}` and the index is ordered as such `{_id, token, device_id}`

Comment: Yes, i will pay attention on the order. Thanks @Sammaye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to create a compound index on fields and index those fields separately.

If you create a compound index like this:

```
db.coll.ensureIndex({_id : 1, token : 1,device_id: 1});
```

This index will support queries on prefix on the index fields:
The following queres will be supported by the compound index:

```
db.coll.find({ _id : ObjectId(....), token : "foo"});
db.coll.find({ _id : ObjectId(....), token : "foo", device_id: 12345});
```

When you have a compound index on those fields, you can also create an index on a single field (e.g. on fields like `token` or `device_id`).

As Sammaye suggested in the comments. The last case will probably require 3 separate indexes on `device_id`, `userid` and `facebook_id` fields (a unique index on `_id` field is created by default, so you don't need to create it).